# Angular 2 RC.5 FormsModule doesn't exist

Tags: angular

I am upgrading from rc.4 to rc.5 and all of the documentation I've found tells me that I should import the FormsModule into my app.module.ts file

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

However when I try to do that I get an error that says the app cannot resolve symbol 'FormsModule'.

I have tried doing `npm install @angular/forms -D` which downloaded and installed @angular/forms in my node_modules, but that didn't help. I also tried updating my typescript to 1.8.10 and my typings to 1.3.3 then running `typings install`, but again that didn't fix it.

What am I missing here? Is the documentation incorrect?

References: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html
and https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/08/13/updating-your-angular-2-app-from-rc4-to-rc5-a-practical-guide/

Comment: are you sure that your package.json, the form dependency looks like this "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",

Comment: I have this, @angular/forms": "^0.2.0"

Comment: @efarley you need to change it to 0.3.0 in order to use FormsModule. Change to 0.3.0 then run `npm install` again

Comment: That was it, updating to 0.3.0 and doing typings install fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to rc.5 also requires updating @angular/forms to 0.3.0.